# Can't install backpack genreators.Laravel version 7.10

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, crud

I have a freshly installed Laravel 7.10.* I want to install the Backpack `composer require backpack/generators --dev`  but cannot install the generators. Here is the error.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.10.3, required  ^7.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.10.3].
- Installation request for backpack/generators ^3.0 -> satisfiable by backck/generators[3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: backpack/crud[4.1.x-dev, 4.0.61].
- Can only install one of: backpack/crud[4.1.x-dev, 4.0.61].
- Can only install one of: backpack/crud[4.1.x-dev, 4.0.61].
- Conclusion: install backpack/crud 4.1.x-dev
- Installation request for backpack/crud (locked at 4.0.61, required as 4.*) -> satisfiable by backpack/crud[4.0.61].`

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

This is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "backpack/crud": "4.0.*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the composer.json?

Comment: Yes. I can show

Comment: You can look sorry my syntax

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve this?

Comment: Yes. This(down below) Answer help me to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you locked the `backpack/crud` version as `4.0.*`, but for the `backpack/generators` the satisfiable versions are these: `4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.x-dev`

So you should change this line in your `composer.json`:

```
"backpack/crud": "4.0.*",
```

to this:

```
"backpack/crud": "4.1.*",
```

then update the composer packages:

```
composer update
```

and finally install the generator package:

```
composer require backpack/generators --dev
```

Comment: Big Thank's it's Work!